# Why is button behaving like a block element?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Why is button behaving like a block element when it is a block-inline element? Input tag is inline as well so the code below should show input ang button besides each other horizontally but inteads it is showing one on top of another using Bootstrap 4.

```
<button type="button" style="display: inline" class="btn btn-primary">C</button>
<input type="text" style="display: inline" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
```

Comment: You should group them, so have a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.form-control` has `width: 100%;`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" style="display: inline" class="btn btn-primary">C</button> 
<input type="text" style="display: inline" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
```

Set `width: auto;` and it displays `inline` as expected

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" style="display: inline" class="btn btn-primary">C</button> 
<input type="text" style="display: inline; width: auto;" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstraps concept is a grid layout structure, so by simply grouping them will make it work fine, and it will scale and use available space properly (width in this case)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">C</button> 
  </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```